# ViewController won't rotate in storyboard, despite being in landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uistoryboard

My ViewController won't rotate in storyboard, despite being set to landscape. Furthermore the device orientation have been set to only allow landscape. What am i missing?
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have "Use Size Classes" selected.  Try this link: [Enabling Size Classes in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014436-CH1-SW1)

Comment: I'm having this issue, but I WANT to use size classes. Why won't autorotate work?

Comment: I have not used size classes but I took a look at the linked article and also the related article "About Designing for Multiple Size Classes" and I think the idea is that you design against a generic square screen, then use the preview mode to see what it will look like in different screen sizes and orientations.  I have never tried.

Comment: I figured out what was going on. For some reason, if you are using size classes, but only have one size class actually defined, auto-rotation will not work. Once you define a second size class, everything works just fine.